# What are the list of methods available in IIS ftp logging?

Tags: ftp, logging, iis, iis-7

According to [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738725(v=ws.10)#table-104-example-of-a-w3c-extended-log-file-entry-from-an-ftp-site), the logs include a variable called `cs-method` which represents the method that is taking place during a ftp session call.

I found a reference for a bunch of these methods used in ftp by checking the list of supported commands using this [technique](https://serverfault.com/a/854668).

However I was able to find some more methods such as, `ControlChannelOpened, ControlChannelClosed, DataChannelOpened & DataChannelClosed` in the log files.

What are the list of methods available in IIS ftp logging? TIA.

Comment: I don't believe there is documentation for all these methods.

Comment: Well, are there any more methods than these?

Comment: Some of these are not really methods but internal actions of IIS.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, are there any other possible values, that I could get in the log files?

Answer (score 0):

[This webpage](https://help.globalscape.com/help/archive/eft6-4/mergedprojects/eft/specifyinglogformattypeandlocation.htm) has what seems like a fairly comprehensive list, which I shall include here. Oddly it has missed *GET*.

| Code | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ABOR | Abort an active file transfer |
| ACCT | Account information |
| ALLO | Allocate sufficient disk space to receive a file |
| APPE | Append |
| AUTH | Authentication/Security Mechanism |
| CCC | Clear Command Channel |
| CDUP | Change to Parent Directory |
| CHANGEPASSWORD | Change the password |
| CLIENTCERT | Client SSL certificate was rejected (reason is provided in the log entry). |
| COMB | Combines file segments into a single file on EFT Server. |
| CREATED | File was created (uploaded). |
| CWD | Change working directory |
| DELE | Delete file |
| EPRT | Specifies an extended address and port to which the server should connect |
| EPSV | Enter extended passive mode |
| FEAT | Get the feature list implemented by the server |
| HELP | Display a list of all available FTP commands |
| KICK | Client connection was closed by administrator. |
| LIST | Returns information of a file or directory if specified, else information of the current working directory is returned |
| MDTM | Return the last-modified time of a specified file |
| MKD | Make directory |
| MLSD | Lists the contents of a directory if a directory is named |
| MLST | Provides data about exactly the object named on its command line, and no others |
| MODE | Sets the transfer mode (Stream, Block, or Compressed) |
| NLIST | Returns a list of file names in a specified directory |
| NOOP | No operation (dummy packet; used mostly on keepalives) |
| OPTS | Select options for a feature |
| PASS | Authentication password |
| PASV | Enter passive mode |
| PBSZ | Protection Buffer Size |
| PORT | Specifies the port to which the server should connect |
| PROT | Data Channel Protection Level |
| PWD | Print working directory Returns the current directory of the host |
| QUIT | Disconnect |
| REIN | Re initializes the connection |
| REST | Restart transfer from the specified point |
| RETR | Transfer a copy of the file |
| RMD | Remove a directory |
| RNFR | Rename from |
| RNTO | Rename to |
| SENT | File was sent (downloaded). |
| SITE | Sends site specific commands to remote server |
| SIZE | Return the size of a file |
| SMNT | Mount file structure |
| SSCN | Set secured client negotiation |
| SSH_DISCONNECT | SFTP (SSH) client connection was closed (reason is provided in the log entry). |
| STAT | Returns the status |
| STOR | Accept the data and to store the data as a file at the server site |
| STOU | Store file uniquely |
| STRU | Set file transfer structure |
| SYST | Return system type |
| TYPE | Sets the transfer mode |
| USER | Authentication username |
| WEBSERVICE | Web Service was invoked. |
| XCRC | Compute CRC32 checksum on specified file |